# Can iPods (3rd gen) brick completely if left uncharged?

Tags: ipod, battery

I have an old 3rd generation iPod, barely used it since I got an iPhone a couple of years ago. I wasn't expecting the battery to hold its charge anymore (I've replaced it once or twice already, infact), but even when plugged in there is no reaction, the device is just dead.

Is this the natural conclusion of leaving it idle/flat for many months? Or do you think there is another problem with the device? (I could perhaps get a replacement battery but I'm not sure that would help)

Comment: How long have you left it plugged in?

Comment: i tried a few hours i think and still no signs of a circuit. as per mspasov's comment below, however, I will perhaps try for longer. i'm not surprised that the battery doesn't work any more but i expected plugging it in would at least give you a complete circuit to power the device

Comment: oh wow it just came back to life. must have been a faulty wire or socket somewhere (it may not hold its charge when it's recharged but it could still be useful). unless that previous attempt to charge had helped.

Comment: Thats why I asked how long you left it charging (I never had a chance to write an actual answer). Ive had a few of these devices get to no charge, and sometimes it takes a bit after plugging it in to even get a charge enough to cut on

Answer (score 2):

Lithium-ion polymer batteries should not be deep discharged. This is a quote from [Lithium-ion Polymer wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_polymer_battery)

> During discharge on load, the load has to be removed as soon as the voltage drops below approximately 3.0 V per cell (used in a series combination), or else the battery will subsequently no longer accept a full charge and may experience problems holding voltage under load. This can be achieved, as with other lithium-ion batteries, also harmed by under- and over-voltage, by circuitry that prevents overcharge and deep discharge.

So discharging batteries below some threshold will make it unable to recharge. The best way to store your battery is to keep it charged around 50%.

On the [Apple Batteries iPod](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipods.html) page, Apple says that you should:

> Use iPod Regularly
>   For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. Be sure to go through at least one charge cycle per month. If you use your iPod infrequently (gasp), you might want to add a reminder to your calendar program

So my conclusion is that your usage pattern could be a probable cause for your battery problem.

Comment: has it right. I will say, though, that I've heard many tales (including 2nd hand from personal friends) that when it appears to be dead this way, sometimes charging it for days -- sometimes even a week or two -- will bring it back to life.

Comment: Worth trying what Matthew suggested